# Link rel="next" and rel="previous" pagination in header

Tags: pagination, seo

how can i apply [pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html) to pagination in the header?

i want to add

`<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3" />`

and

`<link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=1" />`

on pagination page 2, and so on. with an exception for the first and last page.
last page should only contain the rel="prev" and the first page should only contain rel="next"

this would not be too hard to get in the body within the current `{paginate}` tags,
as i see in many other solutions, but i want it in the header as stated in the article above by Google.

anyone has an idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: What do you want to paginate? Span an article across multiple pages? Or link a series of articles?

Comment: i want to paginate entries multiple article links per page

Comment: Ok, but do you want to put every product on a page or link the pages of the list of products?

Comment: the product list :)

Comment: I see. There's more than one way to do this. How are you filling the `<title>`? Please, add a sample code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with a [sample pagination code](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/pagination.html#pagination-links) from the user guide.

```
{paginate}
  {pagination_links}
    <ul>
      {first_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
      {/first_page}

      {previous_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
        {layout:set name="previous_page"}{pagination_url}{/layout:set}
      {/previous_page}

      {page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
      {/page}

      {next_page}
        {layout:set name="next_page"}{pagination_url}{/layout:set}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
      {/next_page}

      {last_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
      {/last_page}
    </ul>
  {/pagination_links}
{/paginate}
```

On the pagination tags, set the [layout variables](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/layouts.html#layout-variables).

(Yeah, I know! `layout:set` should have a `output='yes'` parameter!).

Then, on your layout template:

```
{if layout:next_page}<link rel="next" href="{layout:next_page}" />{/if}
{if layout:previous_page}<link rel="prev" href="{layout:previous_page}" />{/if}
```

This could work with an `embed` too.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could create rel prev and next links within paginated pages was to create a separate extension. This is where pagination is displayed with /P## within the url for the page numbers. This works fine for what I need and have tested it on EE2.9 but should work on later versions.

I'd be interested to know if this is of use to anyone as this has been a long standing problem where I've not been able to create rel links before.

It can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/ignetic/ee-pagination-rel-links

Comment: Can you, please, try my code? I can't do that right now.